# SQL - Explanation about converting date to numbers and checking if parameter is between the range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm adapting some code, and I found this query:

```
SELECT <some columns>
FROM sample_table AS M
WHERE YEAR(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 365 + MONTH(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 30 + DAY(@BETWEEN_DATE)
BETWEEN (
       YEAR(M.STARTINGDATE) * 365 + MONTH(M.STARTINGDATE) * 
       30 + DAY(M.STARTINGDATE)
   )
   AND 
   CASE 
        WHEN M.ENDINGDATE IS NULL THEN (
                 YEAR('99990101') * 365 + MONTH('99990101') * 30 + DAY('19000101')
             )
        ELSE (
                 YEAR(M.ENDINGDATE) * 365 + MONTH(M.ENDINGDATE)
                 * 30 + DAY(M.ENDINGDATE)
             )
   END
```

From the previous query, the `@BETWEEN_DATE` parameter is converted in numbers, but that logic is too confusing for me, honestly.

**EDIT**: The data type of the paramter `@BETWEEN_DATE` and the columns `M.STARTINGDATE` and `M.ENDINGDATE` are `DATETIME`.

---

> I can imagen that `@BETWEEN_DATE` is converted to number for validate if `M.STARTINGDATE` and `M.ENDINGDATE` are between the range. Those starting and ending dates are operated in that way for aggregate a year to the value in `M.STARTINGDATE` and `M.ENDINGDATE` columns; but; I'm not entirely sure.

The result "in the case there parameter `@BETWEEN_DATE` is `2020-06-18 00:00:00.000`", the values for year, month, and day are as follows:

```
DECLARE @BETWEEN_DATE DATETIME = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
SELECT @BETWEEN_DATE AS FECHA, YEAR(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 365 + MONTH(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 30 + DAY(@BETWEEN_DATE) AS NUMERIC_RESULT, 
YEAR(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 365 AS _YEAR,
MONTH(@BETWEEN_DATE) * 30 AS _MONTH, 
DAY(@BETWEEN_DATE) AS _DAY;

Year: 737300
Month: 180
Day: 18
```

I want modify this query and undestand it for make it more legible/simple to understand.

Comment: What is the data type of @BETWEEN_DATE and the columns STARTINGDATE and ENDINGDATE?

Comment: @forpas both are `DATETIME`. Question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query returns all the rows of the table where the value of the variable `@BETWEEN_DATE` is between the date parts of `STARTINGDATE` and `ENDINGDATE`, but it does this in an unnecessary complicated way.
Try this simplified version:

```
SELECT <some columns>
FROM sample_table
WHERE @BETWEEN_DATE >= CONVERT(DATE, STARTINGDATE) 
AND (ENDINGDATE IS NULL OR @BETWEEN_DATE <= CONVERT(DATE, M.ENDINGDATE))
```